# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\arsalan\practice\next\portfolio\.next\prerender-manifest.json']

Tags: next.js, next.js13

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/248p0.png)Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\arsalan\practice\next\portfolio.next\prerender-manifest.json']
I am getting this error when locally make build and try to server it
also, build making end with this
Export encountered errors on following paths:
/page: /
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Does anyone know about this issue